# Is this a fake LEGO torso?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I recently purchased a new 52 Nightwing LEGO minifigure from Bricklink, to replace my damaged one, but I think it may be fake.

I compared the two, and I found a few differences, which I have not seen on a LEGO torso before:

1. ridges / grooves around the neck
2. a slimmer print on the neck
3. and the edge of the torso is a little wider

BUT, there IS a LEGO stamp on the top of the neck.
Can anyone confirm if they have seen this before or if the torso is fake?

Here are the images: The order is real, suspected fake, comparison between torso edges:

[image: Real torso]

[image: Suspected fake]

[image: Torso edges comparison]

Comment: I wouldn't worry about neck print difference. It isn't essential and simply used to mark the front.

Answer (score 1):

I note the printing of the light gray doesn't line up on the sides compared to the dark red texture line. The light gray on the top is in the same position relative to the red printing, but on the questionable torso the light gray printing doesn't continue the dark red printing.

The dark red printing on the questionable torso seems to be in absolutely the correct position; the known torso seems offset a little to the left. Thus the observation that the light grey printing on the sides being out of place.

The light gray printing would be placed in a single pass, so I think your suspicion that this is a fake is not unreasonable, but given the imperfection of the original, I'm not willing to make a definitive call.

[image: Your reference torso]

[image: Your unknown torso]